# i3wm : start applications on specific workspaces when i3 starts

Tags: window-manager, startup, i3

How can I start applications on specific workspaces in i3 when it starts?

Why is this not working in my config file? :

```
workspace 1; exec firefox; workspace 2; exec chromium; workspace 1
```

Answer (score 93, accepted):

According to the [Arch Wiki i3 page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/I3#Launching_programs_on_specific_workspaces), to autostart an application on a specific workspace, you use `i3-msg`:

```
exec --no-startup-id i3-msg 'workspace 1:Web; exec /usr/bin/firefox'
```

Comment: Yes, a line like `exec --no-startup-id i3-msg 'workspace 1; exec firefox; workspace 2; exec urxvt; workspace 1'` works. But, I find it a little odd to use `exec` on `i3-msg` which is a command meant to execute i3 commands. Why can't I directly write `workspace 1; exec firefox; workspace 2; exec urxvt; workspace 1` in my config file?

Comment: This just opens everything in Workspace 1 for me.

Comment: Works for most apps. However `google-chrome-stable` always opens on the last workspace in my setup. For example, with [this configuration](http://pastebin.com/i7d0LvLL), Chrome opens on workspace 4 next to htop.

Comment: Note that i3 now provides [layout saving/restoring](https://i3wm.org/docs/layout-saving.html) features that make it unnecessary to call i3-msg in most cases.

Comment: @Wieland you should just edit that in to the answer...

Comment: @danijar I would imagine it is because the amount of time it takes to startup Chrome exceeds the amount of time it takes to switch to workspace 4 and open urxvt. Google is smart and knows that the sooner it can get you a window the better, but they do this by returning "success" to the executing terminal/application (eg exec) ASAP and then loading the browser in a forked process, which is why exec thinks it was done with Chrome and it moved to the next line in your config. Add `&& sleep 3` and I'd bet Chrome opens in workspace 3. May need to go as high as 5 depending on # of extensions.

Comment: @dragon788 I ended up opening all other applications first then switching to the workspace where I want chrome to show up. That way I don't introduce any unnecessary delay.

Comment: @Wieland layout [saving/restoring](https://i3wm.org/docs/layout-saving.html "saving/restoring") is different from [auto start](https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#_automatically_starting_applications_on_i3_startup "auto start"); the former only deals with setting up [swallow](https://i3wm.org/docs/layout-saving.html#EditingLayoutFiles "swallow") traps for program windows while the latter starts an instance of an application as the OP requested.

Comment: You might wish to update this answer.  This formulation opens all applications in the same workspace, the one defined in the first `i3-msg` command in the config file. This might have functioned in older versions of i3, but seems no longer valid.

Comment: I'm seeing the Chrome behavior described above affect Electron applications. This isn't surprising, but I thought it'd be worth mentioning for others finding their way here.

Comment: For Chrome, I thought it wasn't respecting my workspace at first because it was going into a tab on the wrong workspace, where a Chrome instance was already open. (This was after i3 had fully loaded, not in my config.) Using `new-window` fixed it: `i3-msg 'workspace 2; exec google-chrome --new-window https://example.com'`

Comment: [Assigning workspaces](https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#assign_workspace) work more reliably for me.

Comment: how to place multiple windows in horizontal?

Comment: how to open it in tabbed mode?

Answer (score 25):

```
# This is what I use in ie config
# custom variables for workspaces
set $ws1 "1< txt >"
set $ws2 "2> fm "
set $ws3 "3< Web >"
set $ws4 4
set $ws5 5
set $ws6 6
set $ws7 7
set $ws8 8
set $ws9 9


##==================================================##
#                         *** Workspace specific settings ***                     #
##=================================================##
# Assign Workspaces:
assign [class="Firefox"] $ws3
assign [class="Chromium"] $ws3
assign [class="Google-chrome-beta"] $ws3
assign [class="^Geany"] $ws1
```

NOTE: to apply config, you can use:

`i3-msg reload`

Comment: This works for some applications, but not for others. I suspect it could be related with the string used in the `class` argument. Is there any way to know exactly to which class is an application associated?

Comment: @LuísdeSousa you `xprop | grep CLASS` in terminal, your mouse pointer changes into a crosshair, you click on the program you want to get the class of and use the second variable that comes up in your terminal. Example result for Chrome: `WM_CLASS(STRING) = "google-chrome", "Google-chrome"`

Comment: @kittenparry. Thank you for the suggestion, but still using the string from the `xprop` command the windows are not assigned to the desired workspace.

Comment: @LuísdeSousa some programs don't work with it like Spotify. For them you might write something similar to this `for_window [class="Spotify"] move to workspace $ws10` where `$ws10` is your workspace variable.

Answer (score 16):

It's an autostart on workspace launch only, not an autostart when i3 starts but I thought it could be useful.

For example, to launch my web browser in the named second workspace "web" this is what I did in my config :

`bindsym $mod+2 workspace 2:web; layout tabbed; exec [ $(ps h -C vimb | wc -l) = 0 ] && /usr/bin/vimb -s`

When I hit key 2, my web browser starts but when it's already opened it didn't relaunch it, it just switch to the web workspace.

Note: the layout part can be annoying sometime, it's not a requirement.

For more details see [my conf](https://github.com/tyjak/archlinux/blob/master/.config/i3/config)

Comment: You can do it much easily [by assigning workspace](https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#assign_workspace). For example to move `pidgin` to 3-rd workspace on its every launch, I have in the config `assign [class="Pidgin"] $tag3`.

Comment: Assigning to a workspace is different. @tyjak's solution will cause an application to launch when you open a particular workspace. Assigning an application to a workspace will cause that application to be moved to a workspace whenever you open it.

Answer (score 11):

I just got it working with this at the end of my `~/.config/i3/config` file:

```
for_window [class="Firefox"] move container to workspace 2
exec --no-startup-id firefox
```

Comment: According to [Arch Linux i3](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/I3#Workspace_variables)


Example for Firefox: First set your variable `set $ws1 "Firefox"` and then insert following line `for_window [class="Firefox"] move to workspace $ws1`

Comment: Thank you. It works for me.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `assign [class="<use your program name here e.g. - Firefox>"] $workspace<eg. 5>`. 
It is working for me.