# Open a specific application in a *new* workspace with i3wm

Tags: window-management, i3

My question is something like [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96798/i3wm-start-applications-on-specific-workspaces-when-i3-starts) - but I don't want to open a given application on a specific workspace, I want each instance to open on a new workspace each time.

The OP in the linked-to question wants to open Firefox on workspace 2, Chromium on workspace 1, etc...

I want to open new instances of a text-editor (Sublime Text) in a new workspace for every new instance.  Is this possible?

*solution*:

I used the accepted answer in a modified form:

```
# .bashrc
...
function sublime {
  i3-msg workspace $(($(i3-msg -t get_workspaces | tr , '\n' | grep '"num":' | cut -d : -f 2 | sort -rn | head -1) + 1))
  /usr/bin/sublime_text_3/sublime_text $1
}
```

so that I can use it like this:

```
$ sublime /path/to/file
```

and also because I'm using my dotfiles across several computers, so it's nicer to include everything in one place!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a small BASH script to do that:

This opens a new workspace (taken from [here](https://faq.i3wm.org/question/995/automatically-create-next-numbered-workspace-in-current-screen/)) and runs a command:

```
#!/bin/bash
i3-msg workspace $(($(i3-msg -t get_workspaces | tr , '\n' | grep '"num":' | cut -d : -f 2 | sort -rn | head -1) + 1))
sublime-text
```

Create this script under `/usr/bin`, name it eg. `sublime-new`, give it exec permissions and you can now launch it from a terminal emulator. Strange, but when executing the script from `dmenu`, it first opens the program and then changes the workspace.

Comment: works great, thanks.  I modified it a bit, will add to my original post.  cheers!

Comment: Or more generally `exec "$@"` to use it with other stuff!

Comment: @illuminÉ, it's a good idea to generalize the script, but if the OP needs it for only a specific application, then it might be more useful not requiring to type in another argument.