# i3wm: Start applications without class attribute on specific workspaces

Tags: terminal, i3, workspaces

I've recently installed the i3 window manager on Arch Linux. I have been able to set everything up except the opening of apps into certain workspaces because some applications can only be opened via terminal (for e.g. the terminal mail client "mutt") because they do not have class names which could be found using xprop. So I'd like to know how to use the following command for those special apps without classes. My chromium browser has a class which can be used to identify the application:

```
assign [class="Chromium-browser"] $workspace3
```

*Note: [i3wm : start applications on specific workspaces when i3 starts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96798/i3wm-start-applications-on-specific-workspaces-when-i3-starts) is NOT a duplicate.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Despite the [manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/uxterm) page telling you that you shouldn't use `-class` as it is used by the wrapper, there don't appear to be any side effects from adding this on the command line. This suggests that you can start `mutt` by

```
uxterm -class Mutt -e mutt
```

If this doesn't work then just copying the uxterm shell script and altering the class being set is another option.

Comment: How would I use the -class tag for non-terminal applications such as TeamSpeak 3?

Comment: Depends on the application. It would be unusual for it not to have a usable class, maybe you just need to run `xlsclients -l` to find out what it is. Depending on the toolkit used (if any) it might accept `-name` or there is a general backdoor with `-xrm`

Comment: In regards to the advice *not* to use `-class`: This has mostly to do with the use of X resources. If in your `~/.Xresources` you have settings specifically for `UXTerm` then `uxterm` will use these settings only if the windows actually has the class `UXTerm`. If you have no specific settings, there is nothing to worry about. Even if you do have some settings, you can just copy them for `Mutt`. That way you can even set up mutt  differently than your normal terminal.