# How to autostart more than one app in different workspaces in i3wm

Tags: startup, i3, workspaces

I'm trying to start different apps in different workspaces *without using classes*.

I have already tried the suggestion at [start applications on specific workspaces when i3 starts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/97081/14650)
by including in `i3/config`:

```
exec --no-startup-id i3-msg 'workspace 1; exec /usr/bin/firefox'
exec --no-startup-id i3-msg 'workspace 2; exec /usr/bin/emacsclient -c'
```

But it opens **both** apps in same workspace (**1**).

How can I open *Firefox* in workspace 1 and *Emacs* in workspace 2?

- Not using classes so If I want to open another instance of the same app in a different workspace I should be able to do it.

Related but no duplicate: [Start applications without class attribute on specific workspaces](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/342654/14650)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar issue when first using i3. I found the easiest solution was simply to add in a quick `sleep` in-between each application. As an example, this is part of my startup commands section of my `i3/config`:

```
exec --no-startup-id sh -c 'sleep 1; i3-msg "workspace 10: <icon>"'
exec --no-startup-id "sh -c 'sleep 2; exec gnome-terminal --working-directory=/media/Data/Music -e ranger'"
exec --no-startup-id sh -c 'sleep 3; i3-msg "splitv"'
exec --no-startup-id sh -c 'sleep 4; exec gnome-terminal -e cava'
exec --no-startup-id sh -c 'sleep 5; i3-msg "focus up"; i3-msg "splith"'
exec --no-startup-id sh -c 'sleep 6; i3-msg "workspace 3: <icon>"'
```

This switches to different workspaces and opens up different applications/terminals.

Comment: I played around with it, and I managed to bring down the sleep time to 0.2. It makes it 5 times faster. Any lower (for me) and you don't get enough time between applications.